# Can I add logic to unattended-upgrades?

Tags: 14.04, unattended-upgrades

I'd like to add some logic to unattended upgrades, but am unsure how to do so.  Here's what I'd like to do: If there are security updates, run command exampleCommand1, then proceed with updates. If no reboot is required after updates are installed, run command exampleCommand2 followed by exampleCommand3.  If reboot is required, run command exampleCommand4, then reboot.

Answer (score -2):

Reboot is required only after if you want to update kernel by running the command **"apt-get dist-upgrade"** other upgrades do not require reboot of server. This **"apt-get dist-upgrade"** updates your system only if there is new kernel available.

Comment: Not very helpful response.

Comment: agreed, this response wasn't helpful, but I don't fault you for it.